# Unable to mount network share after update

Tags: networking, mount, updates, samba

I was able to mount a Samba share last night, but after installing updates on my Ubuntu box it now says the "host is down". It installed/updated HUNDREDS of packages, so finding one that is the culprit will be hard, but I've included the full list below (I know it's kind of ridiculous and you'll probably just flame me, but hoping someone knows the culprit and can confirm it's in the list)

I have absolutely narrowed it to the updates, just not sure which one. I have been trying to diagnose/confirm since I had this issue appear on my system, so I created a base VM, confirmed share mounted, cloned it, then ran the updates on one. The one before the updates works, the one IMMEDIATELY after does not (both running at the same time - ie- the host is up and functional for one but not the other)

Below are the packages that were updated. One that stands out to me is libsmbclient, but trying to remove it also wants to remove other packages like gnome-control-center and ubuntu-desktop. There is only the current version in the repository so apt-get can't downgrade.

Finally, I'm still able to find and browse the share in Nautilus, though I'm not able to mount it there, either (keeps prompting for password even though it's correct - again I can mount on my pre-update VM just fine).

Any idea which one would be the culprit or how I would go about reverting to prior versions individually to find it?

Install/Update:

```
 adium-theme-ubuntu:amd64 (0.3.4-0ubuntu2, 0.3.4-0ubuntu4)
 adwaita-icon-theme:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 apparmor:amd64 (2.11.0-2ubuntu16, 2.11.0-2ubuntu17)
 apt:amd64 (1.5~rc3, 1.5~rc4)
 apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.5~rc3, 1.5~rc4)
 apt-utils:amd64 (1.5~rc3, 1.5~rc4)
 at-spi2-core:amd64 (2.25.91-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-2)
 bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 binutils:amd64 (2.29-8ubuntu1, 2.29.1-1ubuntu1)
 binutils-common:amd64 (2.29-8ubuntu1, 2.29.1-1ubuntu1)
 binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu:amd64 (2.29-8ubuntu1, 2.29.1-1ubuntu1)
 bluez:amd64 (5.46-0ubuntu2, 5.46-0ubuntu3)
 bluez-cups:amd64 (5.46-0ubuntu2, 5.46-0ubuntu3)
 bluez-obexd:amd64 (5.46-0ubuntu2, 5.46-0ubuntu3)
 console-setup:amd64 (1.166ubuntu4, 1.166ubuntu5)
 console-setup-linux:amd64 (1.166ubuntu4, 1.166ubuntu5)
 cpp-6:amd64 (6.4.0-4ubuntu1, 6.4.0-7ubuntu1)
 cpp-7:amd64 (7.2.0-3ubuntu1, 7.2.0-6ubuntu1)
 cpp:amd64 (4:7.1.0-1ubuntu3, 4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1)
 cups:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-browsed:amd64 (1.17.4-1, 1.17.5-1ubuntu1)
 cups-bsd:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-client:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-common:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-core-drivers:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-daemon:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-filters:amd64 (1.17.4-1, 1.17.5-1ubuntu1)
 cups-filters-core-drivers:amd64 (1.17.4-1, 1.17.5-1ubuntu1)
 cups-ipp-utils:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-ppdc:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 cups-server-common:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 deja-dup:amd64 (36.0-0ubuntu1, 36.1-0ubuntu1)
 dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 file:amd64 (1:5.31-1, 1:5.32-1)
 file-roller:amd64 (3.25.1-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (2:102.10+LibO5.4.0-0ubuntu2, 2:102.10+LibO5.4.1-0ubuntu1)
 gcc-6-base:amd64 (6.4.0-4ubuntu1, 6.4.0-7ubuntu1)
 gcc-7-base:amd64 (7.2.0-3ubuntu1, 7.2.0-6ubuntu1)
 gdb:amd64 (8.0-0ubuntu6, 8.0.1-0ubuntu1)
 gdbserver:amd64 (8.0-0ubuntu6, 8.0.1-0ubuntu1)
 gdm3:amd64 (3.25.90.1-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 ghostscript:amd64 (9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu2, 9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu3)
 ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu2, 9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu3)
 gir1.2-atk-1.0:amd64 (2.25.90-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-2ubuntu1)
 gir1.2-atspi-2.0:amd64 (2.25.91-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-2)
 gir1.2-clutter-1.0:amd64 (1.26.2+dfsg-1, 1.26.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1)
 gir1.2-freedesktop:amd64 (1.53.2-4, 1.54.0-1)
 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1, 3.24.1-1ubuntu1)
 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.36.5-3, 2.36.10-2)
 gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (3.25.90.1-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 gir1.2-glib-2.0:amd64 (1.53.2-4, 1.54.0-1)
 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64 (3.26.0-1, 3.26.1-1)
 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:amd64 (3.25.91.1-0ubuntu2, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (3.22.19-0ubuntu1, 3.22.21-0ubuntu1)
 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0:amd64 (3.24.3-1, 3.24.4-1)
 gir1.2-gweather-3.0:amd64 (3.25.92-1, 3.26.0-1)
 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.17.92-1, 2.18.0-2)
 gir1.2-mutter-1:amd64 (3.25.91+20170902~ce515c5-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1)
 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu5, 1.8.2-1ubuntu8)
 gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu5, 1.8.2-1ubuntu8)
 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu1, 1.8.4-1ubuntu1)
 gir1.2-pango-1.0:amd64 (1.40.11-1, 1.40.12-1)
 gir1.2-peas-1.0:amd64 (1.21.0-1, 1.22.0-1)
 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0:amd64 (0.99.5-3, 0.99.6-1)
 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.17.92-1, 2.18.0-2)
 gjs:amd64 (1.49.92-1, 1.50.0-1)
 gkbd-capplet:amd64 (3.22.0.1-1, 3.26.0-2)
 glib-networking:amd64 (2.50.0-1, 2.54.0-1)
 glib-networking-common:amd64 (2.50.0-1, 2.54.0-1)
 glib-networking-services:amd64 (2.50.0-1, 2.54.0-1)
 gnome-bluetooth:amd64 (3.26.0-1, 3.26.1-1)
 gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:3.25.92.1-0ubuntu2, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu2)
 gnome-control-center-data:amd64 (1:3.25.92.1-0ubuntu2, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu2)
 gnome-control-center-faces:amd64 (1:3.25.92.1-0ubuntu2, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu2)
 gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 (3.25.91.1-0ubuntu2, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-font-viewer:amd64 (3.25.90-1, 3.26.0-1)
 gnome-getting-started-docs:amd64 (3.24.1-0ubuntu2, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-online-accounts:amd64 (3.25.92-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 gnome-orca:amd64 (3.25.4-0ubuntu2, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 gnome-session-bin:amd64 (3.25.90-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-session-common:amd64 (3.25.90-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-settings-daemon:amd64 (3.25.92-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-settings-daemon-schemas:amd64 (3.25.92-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-shell:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-shell-common:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock:amd64 (0.4, 0.5)
 gnome-software:amd64 (3.25.91-1ubuntu5, 3.26.0-0ubuntu2)
 gnome-software-common:amd64 (3.25.91-1ubuntu5, 3.26.0-0ubuntu2)
 gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 (3.25.91-1ubuntu5, 3.26.0-0ubuntu2)
 gnome-user-docs:amd64 (3.24.2-0ubuntu2, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gnome-user-guide:amd64 (3.24.2-0ubuntu2, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 (3.24.0-0ubuntu1, 3.24.1-1ubuntu1)
 gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.12.2-1ubuntu1, 1.12.3-1ubuntu1)
 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.12.2-1ubuntu1, 1.12.3-1ubuntu1)
 gstreamer1.0-tools:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 gtk-update-icon-cache:amd64 (3.22.19-0ubuntu1, 3.22.21-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs:amd64 (1.33.91-0ubuntu1, 1.34.0-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-backends:amd64 (1.33.91-0ubuntu1, 1.34.0-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-bin:amd64 (1.33.91-0ubuntu1, 1.34.0-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-common:amd64 (1.33.91-0ubuntu1, 1.34.0-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-daemons:amd64 (1.33.91-0ubuntu1, 1.34.0-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-fuse:amd64 (1.33.91-0ubuntu1, 1.34.0-0ubuntu1)
 gvfs-libs:amd64 (1.33.91-0ubuntu1, 1.34.0-0ubuntu1)
 hicolor-icon-theme:amd64 (0.15-1, 0.17-1)
 initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.125ubuntu10, 0.125ubuntu11)
 initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 (0.125ubuntu10, 0.125ubuntu11)
 initramfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.125ubuntu10, 0.125ubuntu11)
 isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.3.5-3ubuntu1, 4.3.5-3ubuntu2)
 isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.3.5-3ubuntu1, 4.3.5-3ubuntu2)
 keyboard-configuration:amd64 (1.166ubuntu4, 1.166ubuntu5)
 language-pack-en:amd64 (1:17.10+20170828, 1:17.10+20170918)
 language-pack-gnome-en:amd64 (1:17.10+20170828, 1:17.10+20170918)
 language-selector-common:amd64 (0.178, 0.180)
 language-selector-gnome:amd64 (0.178, 0.180)
 libapparmor1:amd64 (2.11.0-2ubuntu16, 2.11.0-2ubuntu17)
 libapparmor-perl:amd64 (2.11.0-2ubuntu16, 2.11.0-2ubuntu17)
 libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.5~rc3, 1.5~rc4)
 libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.5~rc3, 1.5~rc4)
 libarchive13:amd64 (3.2.2-2, 3.2.2-3.1)
 libatk1.0-0:amd64 (2.25.90-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-2ubuntu1)
 libatk1.0-data:amd64 (2.25.90-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-2ubuntu1)
 libatk-adaptor:amd64 (2.25.3-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libatk-bridge2.0-0:amd64 (2.25.3-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libatspi2.0-0:amd64 (2.25.91-0ubuntu1, 2.26.0-2)
 libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libbinutils:amd64 (2.29-8ubuntu1, 2.29.1-1ubuntu1)
 libbluetooth3:amd64 (5.46-0ubuntu2, 5.46-0ubuntu3)
 libc6:amd64 (2.24-12ubuntu1, 2.26-0ubuntu1)
 libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.24-12ubuntu1, 2.26-0ubuntu1)
 libcamel-1.2-60:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libc-bin:amd64 (2.24-12ubuntu1, 2.26-0ubuntu1)
 libcc1-0:amd64 (7.2.0-3ubuntu1, 7.2.0-6ubuntu1)
 libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 (1.26.2+dfsg-1, 1.26.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1)
 libclutter-1.0-common:amd64 (1.26.2+dfsg-1, 1.26.2+dfsg-3ubuntu1)
 libcups2:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 libcupscgi1:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 libcupsfilters1:amd64 (1.17.4-1, 1.17.5-1ubuntu1)
 libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 libcupsmime1:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 libcupsppdc1:amd64 (2.2.4-5, 2.2.4-7)
 libcurl3:amd64 (7.55.0-1ubuntu2, 7.55.1-1ubuntu1)
 libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.55.0-1ubuntu2, 7.55.1-1ubuntu1)
 libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libdns-export162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libdw1:amd64 (0.170-0ubuntu2, 0.170-0.1)
 libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libebook-1.2-19:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libebook-contacts-1.2-2:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libecal-1.2-19:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libedata-book-1.2-25:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libedata-cal-1.2-28:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libedataserver-1.2-22:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libedataserverui-1.2-1:amd64 (3.25.91-0ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libegl1-mesa:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libelf1:amd64 (0.170-0ubuntu2, 0.170-0.1)
 libfontembed1:amd64 (1.17.4-1, 1.17.5-1ubuntu1)
 libgail-3-0:amd64 (3.22.19-0ubuntu1, 3.22.21-0ubuntu1)
 libgbm1:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libgcc1:amd64 (1:7.2.0-3ubuntu1, 1:7.2.0-6ubuntu1)
 libgcrypt20:amd64 (1.7.8-2, 1.7.8-2ubuntu1)
 libgd3:amd64 (2.2.4-2ubuntu1, 2.2.5-3)
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.36.5-3, 2.36.10-2)
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin:amd64 (2.36.5-3, 2.36.10-2)
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:amd64 (2.36.5-3, 2.36.10-2)
 libgdm1:amd64 (3.25.90.1-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libgirepository-1.0-1:amd64 (1.53.2-4, 1.54.0-1)
 libgjs0g:amd64 (1.49.92-1, 1.50.0-1)
 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libglapi-mesa:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libgles2-mesa:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.53.6-1ubuntu2, 2.54.0-1ubuntu1)
 libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.53.6-1ubuntu2, 2.54.0-1ubuntu1)
 libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.53.6-1ubuntu2, 2.54.0-1ubuntu1)
 libglibmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 (2.50.1-1, 2.54.1-1)
 libgmime-3.0-0:amd64 (3.0.1-4, 3.0.2-1)
 libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64 (3.26.0-1, 3.26.1-1)
 libgnome-desktop-3-12:amd64 (3.25.91.1-0ubuntu2, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 libgnome-games-support-1-2:amd64 (1.2.2-1, 1.2.3-1)
 libgnome-games-support-common:amd64 (1.2.2-1, 1.2.3-1)
 libgnomekbd8:amd64 (3.22.0.1-1, 3.26.0-2)
 libgnomekbd-common:amd64 (3.22.0.1-1, 3.26.0-2)
 libgoa-1.0-0b:amd64 (3.25.92-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libgoa-1.0-common:amd64 (3.25.92-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libgoa-backend-1.0-1:amd64 (3.25.92-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1ubuntu1)
 libgomp1:amd64 (7.2.0-3ubuntu1, 7.2.0-6ubuntu1)
 libgs9:amd64 (9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu2, 9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu3)
 libgs9-common:amd64 (9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu2, 9.21~dfsg+1-0ubuntu3)
 libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1.12.2-1, 1.12.3-1)
 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.12.2-1ubuntu1, 1.12.3-1ubuntu1)
 libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.22.19-0ubuntu1, 3.22.21-0ubuntu1)
 libgtk-3-bin:amd64 (3.22.19-0ubuntu1, 3.22.21-0ubuntu1)
 libgtk-3-common:amd64 (3.22.19-0ubuntu1, 3.22.21-0ubuntu1)
 libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:amd64 (3.22.1-1, 3.22.2-1)
 libgtksourceview-3.0-1:amd64 (3.24.3-1, 3.24.4-1)
 libgtksourceview-3.0-common:amd64 (3.24.3-1, 3.24.4-1)
 libgweather-3-6:amd64 (3.25.92-1, 3.26.0-1)
 libgweather-common:amd64 (3.25.92-1, 3.26.0-1)
 libidn11:amd64 (1.33-1, 1.33-2)
 libidn2-0:amd64 (2.0.2-4, 2.0.2-5)
 libinput10:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu1)
 libinput-bin:amd64 (1.8.0-1ubuntu1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu1)
 libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libisc-export160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.17.92-1, 2.18.0-2)
 libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 (1.5.1-0ubuntu2, 1.5.2-0ubuntu3)
 libllvm4.0:amd64 (1:4.0.1-4~ubuntu4, 1:4.0.1-5)
 libllvm5.0:amd64 (1:5.0-1ubuntu2, 1:5.0-2)
 liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.5ubuntu1, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-12.6ubuntu1)
 libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.31-1, 1:5.32-1)
 libmagic-mgc:amd64 (1:5.31-1, 1:5.32-1)
 libmbim-glib4:amd64 (1.14.0-1, 1.14.2-1)
 libmbim-proxy:amd64 (1.14.0-1, 1.14.2-1)
 libmpc3:amd64 (1.0.3-1, 1.0.3-2)
 libmutter-1-0:amd64 (3.25.91+20170902~ce515c5-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1)
 libnautilus-extension1a:amd64 (1:3.25.92-0ubuntu1, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 libnm0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu5, 1.8.2-1ubuntu8)
 libnma0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu1, 1.8.4-1ubuntu1)
 libnm-glib4:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu5, 1.8.2-1ubuntu8)
 libnm-gtk0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu1, 1.8.4-1ubuntu1)
 libnm-util2:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu5, 1.8.2-1ubuntu8)
 libnss-myhostname:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 libnss-resolve:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 libpam-systemd:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.11-1, 1.40.12-1)
 libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.11-1, 1.40.12-1)
 libpangoft2-1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.11-1, 1.40.12-1)
 libpangoxft-1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.11-1, 1.40.12-1)
 libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 (1.21.0-1, 1.22.0-1)
 libpeas-common:amd64 (1.21.0-1, 1.22.0-1)
 libperl5.26:amd64 (5.26.0-5, 5.26.0-8ubuntu1)
 libpng16-16:amd64 (1.6.32-1, 1.6.32-2)
 libpulse0:amd64 (1:10.0-2ubuntu2, 1:10.0-2ubuntu3)
 libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:10.0-2ubuntu2, 1:10.0-2ubuntu3)
 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:10.0-2ubuntu2, 1:10.0-2ubuntu3)
 libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-2ubuntu1)
 libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-2ubuntu1)
 libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-2ubuntu1)
 libpython3.6:amd64 (3.6.2-3, 3.6.3~rc1-2ubuntu1)
 libpython3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.2-3, 3.6.3~rc1-2ubuntu1)
 libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.2-3, 3.6.3~rc1-2ubuntu1)
 libpython3-stdlib:amd64 (3.6.1-0ubuntu3, 3.6.2-1ubuntu2)
 libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-1)
 libqpdf18:amd64 (7.0~b1-0ubuntu1, 7.0.0-1)
 libseccomp2:amd64 (2.3.1-2.1ubuntu1, 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu2)
 libselinux1:amd64 (2.6-3build2, 2.7-1)
 libsemanage1:amd64 (2.6-2build2, 2.7-1)
 libsemanage-common:amd64 (2.6-2build2, 2.7-1)
 libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu2, 2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3)
 libsnapd-glib1:amd64 (1.19-0ubuntu1, 1.23-0ubuntu1)
 libstdc++6:amd64 (7.2.0-3ubuntu1, 7.2.0-6ubuntu1)
 libsystemd0:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 libtalloc2:amd64 (2.1.9-2, 2.1.9-2ubuntu1)
 libtiff5:amd64 (4.0.8-4, 4.0.8-5)
 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0:amd64 (1.99.3-1, 2.0.0-1)
 libudev1:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 libupower-glib3:amd64 (0.99.5-3, 0.99.6-1)
 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu2, 2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3)
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.17.92-1, 2.18.0-2)
 libwhoopsie-preferences0:amd64 (0.18build1, automatic)
 libwpd-0.10-10:amd64 (0.10.1-5, 0.10.2-2)
 libxatracker2:amd64 (17.2.0-0ubuntu1, 17.2.1-0ubuntu1)
 libxkbcommon0:amd64 (0.7.1-1, 0.7.1-2)
 libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64 (0.7.1-1, 0.7.1-2)
 light-themes:amd64 (16.10+17.10.20170817-0ubuntu1, 16.10+17.10.20170918-0ubuntu1)
 lintian:amd64 (2.5.52ubuntu2, 2.5.53ubuntu2)
 linux-generic:amd64 (4.12.0.13.14, 4.13.0.11.12)
 linux-headers-4.13.0-11:amd64 (4.13.0-11.12, automatic)
 linux-headers-4.13.0-11-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-11.12, automatic)
 linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.12.0.13.14, 4.13.0.11.12)
 linux-image-4.13.0-11-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-11.12, automatic)
 linux-image-extra-4.13.0-11-generic:amd64 (4.13.0-11.12, automatic)
 linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.12.0.13.14, 4.13.0.11.12)
 locales:amd64 (2.24-12ubuntu1, 2.26-0ubuntu1)
 manpages:amd64 (4.12-2, 4.13-3)
 multiarch-support:amd64 (2.24-12ubuntu1, 2.26-0ubuntu1)
 mutter:amd64 (3.25.91+20170902~ce515c5-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1)
 mutter-common:amd64 (3.25.91+20170902~ce515c5-1ubuntu1, 3.26.0-1)
 nautilus:amd64 (1:3.25.92-0ubuntu1, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 nautilus-data:amd64 (1:3.25.92-0ubuntu1, 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 network-manager:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu5, 1.8.2-1ubuntu8)
 network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu5, 1.8.2-1ubuntu8)
 network-manager-gnome:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu1, 1.8.4-1ubuntu1)
 nplan:amd64 (0.26, 0.29)
 perl:amd64 (5.26.0-5, 5.26.0-8ubuntu1)
 perl-base:amd64 (5.26.0-5, 5.26.0-8ubuntu1)
 perl-modules-5.26:amd64 (5.26.0-5, 5.26.0-8ubuntu1)
 pulseaudio:amd64 (1:10.0-2ubuntu2, 1:10.0-2ubuntu3)
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 (1:10.0-2ubuntu2, 1:10.0-2ubuntu3)
 pulseaudio-utils:amd64 (1:10.0-2ubuntu2, 1:10.0-2ubuntu3)
 python2.7:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-2ubuntu1)
 python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-2ubuntu1)
 python3.6:amd64 (3.6.2-3, 3.6.3~rc1-2ubuntu1)
 python3.6-minimal:amd64 (3.6.2-3, 3.6.3~rc1-2ubuntu1)
 python3:amd64 (3.6.1-0ubuntu3, 3.6.2-1ubuntu2)
 python3-gdbm:amd64 (3.6.2-1ubuntu1, 3.6.3~rc1-0ubuntu1)
 python3-minimal:amd64 (3.6.1-0ubuntu3, 3.6.2-1ubuntu2)
 python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:17.10.9, 1:17.10.10)
 python:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-1)
 python-minimal:amd64 (2.7.13-2, 2.7.14-1)
 python-samba:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu2, 2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3)
 python-talloc:amd64 (2.1.9-2, 2.1.9-2ubuntu1)
 qpdf:amd64 (7.0~b1-0ubuntu1, 7.0.0-1)
 rename:amd64 (0.20-4, 0.20-6)
 samba-common:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu2, 2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3)
 samba-common-bin:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu2, 2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3)
 samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu2, 2:4.6.7+dfsg-1ubuntu3)
 snapd-login-service:amd64 (1.19-0ubuntu1, 1.23-0ubuntu1)
 systemd:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 systemd-sysv:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 ubuntu-artwork:amd64 (1:16.10+17.10.20170817-0ubuntu1, 1:16.10+17.10.20170918-0ubuntu1)
 ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.399, 1.400)
 ubuntu-mono:amd64 (16.10+17.10.20170817-0ubuntu1, 16.10+17.10.20170918-0ubuntu1)
 ubuntu-session:amd64 (3.25.90-0ubuntu4, 3.26.0-0ubuntu1)
 ubuntu-software:amd64 (3.25.91-1ubuntu5, 3.26.0-0ubuntu2)
 ubuntu-standard:amd64 (1.399, 1.400)
 ubuntu-wallpapers:amd64 (17.04.1-0ubuntu1, 17.10.1-0ubuntu1)
 ubuntu-wallpapers-artful:amd64 (17.10.1-0ubuntu1, automatic)
 ubuntu-wallpapers-zesty:amd64 (17.04.1-0ubuntu1, 17.10.1-0ubuntu1)
 udev:amd64 (234-2ubuntu9, 234-2ubuntu10)
 uno-libs3:amd64 (5.4.0-0ubuntu2, 5.4.1-0ubuntu1)
 update-manager:amd64 (1:17.10.9, 1:17.10.10)
 update-manager-core:amd64 (1:17.10.9, 1:17.10.10)
 upower:amd64 (0.99.5-3, 0.99.6-1)
 ure:amd64 (5.4.0-0ubuntu2, 5.4.1-0ubuntu1)
 whoopsie-preferences:amd64 (0.18build1, automatic)
```

Comment: it's the wallpapers for sure ... why blame updates? when the error is 'host is down'.   have you checked the host is 'up'?  can you ping (icmp echo-request) it?  is your networking up?  you've more likely network, or hardware issues I'd guess; unless you modified/setup your networking in a non-standard way which got overwritten by updates (if so do it correctly so its update proof)

Comment: Guess I should have included more information. I have absolutely narrowed it to the updates. I have been trying to diagnose/confirm so I created a VM and cloned it. The one before the updates works, the one IMMEDIATELY after does not (both running at the same time - ie- the host is up and functional for one but not the other). PS - I almost removed the backgrounds one, but left it for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the exact same issue after update to 17.10. There is nothing wrong with the server, it is the Ubuntu client which is broken.

The thing that solved it for me is adding `vers=1.0` to the `fstab` lines mounting the shares. Then it works.

So maybe an update to the kernel is by default using a newer version of smb which has this bug?

Comment: deserves an upvote....after one week..vers option was the problem

Comment: Also had the problem after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- run the `smbstatus` command on the server: see if the samba processes are running, if there are live connections, etc.
- are the smbd and nmbd processes running on the server?
- check `/var/log/samba/log*` on the server. It will log important errors.
- list shares anonymously on the server: `smbclient -L <serverip> -N`
- list shares authenticating yourself before: `smbclient -L <serverip> -U <username>`
- connect to a share with your username: `smbclient //<serverip>/<share> -U <username>`